# Como pegar o valor do GET em Laravel, mesmo quando o método de requisição é POST?

Tags: laravel

Eu estou fazendo uma requisição para uma rota, onde o método da requisição está marcado com o `Any` - ou seja, aceita qualquer método.

```
public function anyIndex()
{
   $nome = Input::get('nome');

   $id   = Input::get('id'); // Queria específico do `GET`, não qualquer um
}
```

URL:

```
 'usuarios/index?nome=Wallace+Souza&id=Teste'
```

O problema é que,  no `Laravel`, o método `Input::get` serve para tudo (`POST`, `PUT`, `GET`). E,  nesse caso específico, quero pegar apenas os valor da query string.

Ou seja, se eu preencher o campo `id` no formulário, e enviar uma requisição `POST`, ainda sim quero pegar somente o que é passado na `url` via `GET`.

Tem como fazer isso no  `Laravel`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vamos lá, vou responder minha própria pergunta, mas não entendam isso mal, eu só quero ajudar algumas pessoas que têm interesse de aprender mais sobre o `Laravel`.

Quando você quer pegar os valores referente somente ao que está na query string, ignorando o que está no `POST` e outros, você pode utilizar o método `Request::query`.

Exemplo - Laravel 5:

```
  public function anyIndex(Request $request)
  {
      $id = $request->query('id'); // Pega somente o da query string
  }
```

Exemplo - Laravel 4:

```
public function getIndex()
{
      $id = Request::query('id');
}
```

Se ainda quiser pegar todos os valores do método `GET` passados como parâmetro da `url`, vocề pode chamar esse método sem argumento.

```
  Request::query();
```

Comment: nesse caso eu não preciso criar as opções la na rota? tipo os /{parametro} que eu citei? Posso deixar so o /index que os dados vão aparecer na url sem estar definido na rota e ainda sim vou conseguir pegar no controller?

Comment: @RaylanSoares nesse caso eu estou falando dos parâmetros `GET`. Talvez você esteja confundindo `pages/15` com `pages/?id=15`. Quando falo `GET` falo do último exemplo

Comment: ahh sim, verdade. Obrigado! rs

Answer (score 2):

Acho que é só vc pegar a variável que vc usou pra receber na rota, não?

Tipo, se vc mandou apenas um parâmetro via `url`, na sua rota deve ter um {parametro}, no seu controller vc pega ele com $parametro. Ex:

**Chamada:**

```
<form action="{{ url('/index',  '05') }}>
```

**Rota:**

```
Route::any('/index/{idPassada}', 'MeuController@anyIndex');
```

**Controller:**

```
public function anyIndex(Request $request, $idPassada)
{
   $nome = Input::get('nome');
   $id   = $idPassada;
}
```

Comment: Isso não é o `GET`. Isso se trata do seguimento da rota. De qualquer forma, obrigado pela resposta. É uma boa opção... +1 ....